# how to get a scanner to read a pre-set variable

Tags: java, interface, java.util.scanner

i am trying to use a scanner to get user input to add a new item to a stock list i have created, the item must possess the attributes itemID, itemDesc, price, quantity, and reorderlevel.

How would i go about reading the user input, and recognising it as one of those variables i've created, and then adding it to my list?

I've had a go, but it doesnt appear to recognise them as my variables

Any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks

MY ATTEMPT:

```
else if (i==1)
    {
        StockListInterface.doAddItem(item);

        System.out.println("Add New Item");
        System.out.println("****************");

        System.out.println("Enter ID    :>");
        Scanner scanner1 = new Scanner(System.in);
        String itemID = scanner1.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Enter Description    :>");
        Scanner scanner2 = new Scanner(System.in);
        String itemDesc = scanner2.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Enter Price    :>");
        Scanner scanner3 = new Scanner(System.in);
        String price = scanner3.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Enter Quantity    :>");
        Scanner scanner4 = new Scanner(System.in);
        String quantity = scanner4.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Enter Re-Order Level    :>");
        Scanner scanner5 = new Scanner(System.in);
        String reOrderLevel = scanner5.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Enter another? (Y/N)    :>");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to create a new Scanner every time you take an input. You can use the previously defined scanner as follows:

```
else if (i==1)
{
    StockListInterface.doAddItem(item);

    System.out.println("Add New Item");
    System.out.println("****************");

    System.out.println("Enter ID    :>");
    Scanner scanner1 = new Scanner(System.in);
    String itemID = scanner1.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Enter Description    :>");
    String itemDesc = scanner1.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Enter Price    :>");
    String price = scanner1.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Enter Quantity    :>");
    String quantity = scanner1.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Enter Re-Order Level    :>");
    String reOrderLevel = scanner1.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Enter another? (Y/N)    :>");
}
```

Also you should consider adding one more line at the end, to get the input of 'Y' or 'N' as follows:

```
String addAnother = scanner1.nextLine();
```

Comment: thank you. how do i make it so that the program recognises that these are variables i want to assign to the item i want to add?

Comment: Suppose you have an object of `Item`, which has a property `id`, then you can say `Item item = new Item();` and `item.setID = itemID`, assuming that `id` is public, or you can call the setters for `id`.

Answer (score 0):

```
One problem in your code i can see is you are creating Object of scanner every time when you get input.

I Suggest you to use class BufferedReader like this. It works perfectly.

BufferedReader br = null
try{
   BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
   String tmp = br.readLine();
  } catch(IOException ie){
System.out.println(e)
}

br.readLine() : always returns String
You need to convert String into related to datatype. Let's say i want to convert that string to integer, Then i can use wrapper class like this

Integer num = Integer.parseInt(tmp);
```

Comment: you will need to surround parseInt with try catch to incase it is not formatted correctly

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create a new scanner every time you want to read input, just use

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
```

and then every time you want to read input use

```
scanner.nextLine()
```

but if you know you're reading in an int etc you can use specific methods like

```
scanner.getInt()
```

see [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) for more information